# How do I create a countdown timer using Hours, Minutes and Seconds?

Tags: vb.net, countdown, timespan

I was wondering how I would go about fixing my countdown timer so that it shows the time in Hours:Minutes:Seconds?

currently, it only outputs the seconds and I'm not sure where I have gone wrong.
Any help is much appreciated.

Code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim TargetDT As DateTime
    Dim fields() As String
    Dim Days, Hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        fields = Split(TextBox1.Text, ":")
        Hours = fields(0)
        minutes = fields(1)
        seconds = fields(2)

        Dim CountDownFrom As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(Hours).FromMinutes(minutes).FromSeconds(seconds)
        Timer1.Interval = 1000
        TargetDT = DateTime.Now.Add(CountDownFrom)
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = TargetDT.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
        If ts.TotalMilliseconds > 0 Then
            Con1Time.Text = ts.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
        Else
            Con1Time.Text = "0:00:00"
            Timer1.Stop()
            MessageBox.Show("Done")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What do you have in `TextBox1.Text`? You can simply have `[TimeSpan] = [DateTimeEnd] - [DateTime.Now]` and format the resulting TimeSpan.

Comment: Textbox1.text is the input, so the user puts in a specified time in the format hh/mm/ss and whatever is inputted, is the timer, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Start by assigning the time you want to countdown to a `TimeSpan` field. When you want to star counting down, call `Start` on a `Timer` and a `Stopwatch`.  In the `Tick` event handler of the `Timer`, get the `Elapsed` of the `Stopwatch` and subtract that from the original time to get the time remaining as a `TimeSpan`.  You can then format and display that.  When that time remaining reaches zero, the countdown has expired.

```
Private countDownTime As TimeSpan
Private countDownWatch As Stopwatch

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    countDownTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
    countDownWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim timeRemaining = countDownTime - countDownWatch.Elapsed

    If timeRemaining < TimeSpan.Zero Then
        timeRemaining = TimeSpan.Zero
    End If

    Label1.Text = timeRemaining.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")

    If timeRemaining = TimeSpan.Zero Then
        Timer1.Stop()

        MessageBox.Show("Countdown complete")
    End If
End Sub
```

That said, your specific issue is here:

```
Dim CountDownFrom As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(Hours).FromMinutes(minutes).FromSeconds(seconds)
```

That does not do what you think it does.  You're only getting the result of the `FromSeconds` call.  If you want to create a `TimeSpan` with hours, minutes and seconds then call the appropriate constructor

```
Dim CountDownFrom As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(Hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Of course, those arguments should be `Integer` values, not `Strings`.  Turn `Option Strict On` and use the proper data types.